# Wait for node.js callback to be completed before ending AJAX request

Tags: ajax, node.js, jquery, express

I am using jQuery on the front to make an AJAX post request using $.post(). I also pass a success function which will do something with the data returned. On my node.js server, I am using express to handle requests, the post request calls another function passing a callback which in the callback does a res.send(). How can I get the request not to finish until the callback is done?

My client-side code is:

```
$.post("/newgroup/", {name: newgroupname}, function(data) {
    console.log(data); // Returns undefined because requests ends before res.send
});
```

My server-side code is:

```
app.post('/newgroup/', function(req, res){
    insertDocument({name:req.body.name, photos:[]}, db.groups, function(doc){
        res.send(doc); 
    });
});
```

The insertDocument function is:

```
function insertDocument(doc, targetCollection, callback) {
    var cursor = targetCollection.find( {}, {_id: 1}).sort({_id: -1}).limit(1);
    cursor.toArray(function(err, docs){
        if (docs == false){
            var seq = 1;
        }
        else {
            var seq = docs[0]._id + 1;
        }
        doc._id = seq;

        targetCollection.insert(doc);
        callback(doc);
    });
}
```

Comment: I think there's something else. That response should send anything until res.send() is called. The $.post() should be waiting for res.send(). Make sure you're not calling it somewhere else.

Comment: Have you verified that the newsgroup post handler is actually being called?

Comment: Have you looked at the network traffic in chrome developer tools or firebug to see the actual XHR being sent, and the response it sends you back?  it would be interesting to see what the actual response looks like, and compare that to the result you are seeing in your `console.log(data)` statement.

Answer (score 1):

If the code you've shown us is the real code then the only possibility is that the thing you are returning `doc` is actually `undefined`. The callback on the client will not fire before `res.send()` is triggered.

Are you sure that the callback in `insertDocument` is exactly as you think? Often callbacks are of the form `function(err,doc)`, i.e. try this:

```
app.post('/newgroup/', function(req, res){
    insertDocument({name:req.body.name, photos:[]}, db.groups, function(err, doc){
        res.send(doc); 
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work for some reason. I added the insertDocument function in the original question. I console log doc in the callback and it is always undefined.

Comment: Also I place a console.log before the callback(doc); and it displays the document correctly, but for some reason when callback sends the document back it becomes undefined. Would this have to do with scope?

Comment: @Jupiter Very weird, indeed. If that's the whole code, then there is nothing that modifies doc variable (I'm not talking about the underlying object), i.e. scoping is not an issue here. I'm not sure how the code you've shown us could result in such outcome to be honest. Perhaps there's something more that's going on that you are not sharing with us?

Comment: I seemed to have figured something out that worked. See my answer below, I think it had something to do with the variable name being the same as the initial parameter, but I don't see why this would do much. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found the answer, I am not sure why this works, I just had to change the name of the variable I was sending to the callback, I assume this is because it had the same name as a parameter, so I changed my insertDocument function to look like this

```
function insertDocument(doc, targetCollection, callback) {
    var cursor = targetCollection.find( {}, {_id: 1}).sort({_id: -1}).limit(1);
    cursor.toArray(function(err, docs){
        if (docs == false){
            var seq = 1;
        }
        else {
            var seq = docs[0]._id + 1;
        }
        doc._id = seq;

        targetCollection.insert(doc);
        var new_document = doc;
        callback(new_document);
     });
}
```

Comment: That's a heresy. :D I absolutely don't believe that this is the solution.

Comment: @freakish That's exactly what I was thinking, but somehow changing that has caused it to work!

Comment: I don't think this is solving what you think.  See my post above.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be a **sync/async** issue?  I don't know what library you are using for your saves, but is it a case were the call should be something more like this?

```
targetCollection.insert(doc, function(err, saveddoc) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    callback(saveddoc);
});
```

Comment: That's a heresy as well. First of all: `if/else` block **does not** create a scope (only functions do). The code is fine. Secondly: objects are passed via reference. It is impossible to pass a variable to function which will modify it (it may modify the underlying object, but not the variable).

Comment: @freakish Well then, I guess we learn every day.  How about that. Understand the dereferencing issue, late night oversight there...  I'll edit the falsities out for the community.